# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field "n"

Tags: java

I just start learning Java and I try to make my very first code  due to the classic "hello world" but I also put a small modification.

```
 public class example {
         int n= 7;
 public static void main (String[] args){
         System.out.println(" the number here is  "+ n);}}
```

It doesn't work. I looking for some lights.
Thank in advance

Comment: make `n` static.

Comment: just change **int n = 7** to **static int n = 7** and it will start working

Comment: Thank you. It works. Sorry for stupid question. I just pick up Java for an hour.

Comment: @users1210 It will be better if you start using a book for picking up the weight of java :)